# How to make a 2D array in LC3

Tags: arrays, 2d, lc3

I am trying to make a 2D array in LC3. So far I am thinking of initializing a block of memory using .BLKW and then loading into that another array into each entry. This doesn't seem like it will lead me on the right track though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it with .BLKW and also with .STRINGZ, though the latter is admittedly a bit unusual.

The bigger, usual question is around how you decide to "get" and "put" data into that specific area of memory.  There are several ways to do that for sure (no one right answer).

Your initial thoughts are cool and valid, but definitely seem to me to be more complex, especially in LC3.

A more direct "row major" or "column major" form of storage  - where successive memory locations represent the next entry in a row (row major), or alternatively the next entry in a column (column major)) - is the standard way to do this.

Basically you want to allocate that area of memory, and then write two functions: one to put an item at location (r, c), and get an item from location (r,c).

For this, you will hopefully only need to put an item that is small enough to fit into on 16bit memory location for LC3.  That could be a number, or a character.  (bigger than 16 bit is doable but adds more complexity for your program for sure).

If you want a fully roughed out sample, you can find that here: http://lc3tutor.org/#array2Dcolordersmp (or just go to lc3tutor.org and look at the 2D array sample).

If you are wanting to learn and try this on your own, you can just read the description there and ignore the sample code (best if you doing for homework and you want to be sure you learn it).  Otherwise, the code there should run fine in the browser-based lc3 simulator you find referenced there.

Good luck!

Jeff

PS Here's the pre-amble to that code, if you want to just work from this... hopefully this example helps anchor the col major approach taken in the full code sample:

.ORIG x3000

BR MAIN; jump over storage below to the start of the main section

.STRINGZ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ"; slightly tricky - we are storing a sequence of letters in our 2D array for reference.

; The address of the above string STARTS AT x3001,

;   which you will see is the same as the 2D_ARRAY label value below.

; This is essentially our 2D_ARRAY, starting at x3001 and taking up 26 locations,

;   plus 1 (for the null terminator on the string).

; We will assume the 2D array has 13 rows and 2 columns.

; Two letters per row and 13 letters per column. 26 letters.

; So our NUM_ROW label will be 13 and our NUM_COL label will be 2. (see labels below)

; We will treat this array as a column-major stored array.

; Based on our string above, that means the cells of the first

;  column (column #0 by our conventions) are: A-M.

; And the cells of the second column (column #1) are: N-Z.

; If we were storing the array in row-major form, then the cells of the first ROW

;  would be A, B, and the second ROW would be C, D. Etc.

; Like this:

;

;R\C |  0 |  1

;    ------------

; 0  |  A |  N

; 1  |  B |  O

; 2  |  C |  P

; 3  |  D |  Q

; 4  |  E |  R

; 5  |  F |  S

; 6  |  G |  T

; 7  |  H |  U

; 8  |  I |  V

; 9  |  J |  W

; 10 |  K |  X

; 11 |  L |  Y

; 12 |  M  | Z

; such that 2D_ARRAY[ROW=8, COL=1] would be the letter "V"